# OpenVPN client fails to activate pushed DHCP options for DNS and DOMAIN

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, dhcp, openvpn

OpenVPN client is connecting to OpenVPN server OK.

During connection, we see the options pushed contain `dhcp-option` of `DNS 10.0.0.2` and `DOMAIN prd1.o2`:

```
Sun Aug  2 17:31:06 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,explicit-exit-notify,topology subnet,route-delay 5 30,dhcp-pre-release,dhcp-renew,dhcp-release,route-metric 101,ping 10,ping-restart 60,comp-lzo yes,redirect-gateway def1,redirect-gateway bypass-dhcp,redirect-gateway autolocal,route-gateway 10.0.16.129,dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.2,dhcp-option DOMAIN prd1.o2,register-dns,block-ipv6,ifconfig 10.0.16.139 255.255.255.128'
```

However, after connection, even thought the VPN is acting nominally, no changes have been made to `/etc/resolv.conf`.  And yes, I have confirmed that when I disconnect the internet entirely, `/etc/resolv.conf` is immediately modified to contain no entries, *and* when I re-connect the internet, DHCP successfully immediately adds nameserver entries back into `/etc/resolv.conf`.

What am I missing?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/590722/82338

Comment: @ [Gajus](http://superuser.com/users/69534/gajus) Technically, that is the answer. ;-)